# Fabric-java-sdk not found org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.FabricProposalResponse

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

When I updated the fabric-java-sdk version from 1.4.1 to 2.0.0. The app can't be compiled. 
Those classes not found:
"org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.FabricProposalResponse"
"org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.FabricProposal"
"org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.FabricTransaction"

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same problem and it looks like these changed between version 1.4.1 and 2.0.0.

I think `org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.FabricProposalResponse` is now `org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.ProposalResponsePackage`

I didn't need the others but
`org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.ProposalPackage` and `org.hyperledger.fabric.protos.peer.TransactionPackage` would be my guess.